# Elements get out of the div on making the screen responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive, responsiveness

I have the following block of code, The problem with this is that it tends to get out of the `aircard div` when making the screen responsive, I dont know for what reason as shown in the picture,whereas they should stack over one another. What's the reason that they are not being responsive and how can I make them responsive. The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="air-card">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
                    <h2 class="text-center hidden-xs m-sm-bottom ng-scope"> Complete Your Account </h2>
                    <h4 class="text-center ng-binding ng-scope"> Yourname@gmail.com </h4> <br>
                    <form method="POST" action="confirm.html">

                    <!--<i class="fas fa-globe">--><select> <!-- </i> -->
                    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
                    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
</select>  <br> <br>
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Create a Password" required> <br> <br>
            <h4 style="text-align: center;"> I want to: </h4>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" align="center" style="margin-left: 400px; position: relative; border: 1px solid black;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Hire for a Project</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"> Work as a Freelancer </button>
</div> <br> <br>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-left:380px;">
  <!--<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"> <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">-->
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1"">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">  Yes! Send me genuinely useful emails every now and then to help me get the most out of Extolssolutions.  </label> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1"">
</div></label>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-left:380px;">
  <!--<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"> <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">-->
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" required>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1" required> Yes, I understand and agree to the Extols Solutions <a href="#" style="color: green;">Terms of Service </a>, including the <a href="#" style="color: green;">User Agreement </a> <a href="#" style="color: green;"> and Privacy Policy. </a>  </label> <br> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1"">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Next </button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.air-card {
position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 30px  0px;
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(57,73,76,.35);
}

select
{   
    margin-left: 420px;
}

input[type='password']
{

    margin-left: 420px;
    width: 354px;

}

input[type='checkbox']
{
    margin-left: 420px;
    text-align: center;
}

label a:hover
{
    color: green;
}

button[type='submit']
{
    margin-left: 550px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 8%;
}

.row a
{
    color: #747676;
    font-family: Arial,sens-serif;
}
```

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/dupihupugu/1/edit?html,css,console,output

P.S, I'm relatively a newbie to both CSS,Bootstrap 4 as well as Stack overflow,so please go easy on me

[The full screen page][The responsive screen page][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wgbW.png)

Comment: where are your media queries? your css has nothing to denote it being responsive.  https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Comment: @Keoki What media queries do I put in in this case to make it responsive? I'm a newbie so dont know much about them

Comment: please read the link in my comment, and/or google "css media queries for responsive design".

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```css
nav
{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
nav ul li 
{
 text-decoration: none;
}

a.navbar-brand 
{
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-right: 500px;
}

li
{
 text-align: right;
}

p
{
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.footer-navbar-wrapper {
    background-color: #494949;
}

.copyright
{
 color: #E0E0D6;
}

.row a
{
 color: #747676;
 font-family: Arial,sens-serif;
}

footer
{
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 position: relative;
}

.air-card {
position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 30px  0px;
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(57,73,76,.35);
}

select
{   
 margin-left: 420px;
}

input[type='password']
{
 
 
 width: 354px;

}

input[type='checkbox']
{
 
 text-align: center;
}

label a:hover
{
 color: green;
}

button[type='submit']
{
 
 margin-top: 20px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Signup</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <title> Sign Up Module </title>
 <style type="text/css">
  

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header-navbar-wrapper header-navbar-skinny ng-scope" role="banner" data-ng-controller="headerController">
  <nav class="primary-navbar navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.jpg"></a>
   <ul class="navbar-nav">

    <!--<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <span style="color: #6FDA44"> Extols </span> <span style="color: #4B4B4B"> Solutions</span> </a> </li>-->
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <li class="nav-item"> <p> <span class="navbar-text" style="color: #767676">Already Have an Account?</span>  <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #178329">Log in</a></p></li>
    </div>
        </ul>
        </nav>
 </header>
  
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="air-card">
<div class="">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
    <h2 class="text-center hidden-xs m-sm-bottom ng-scope"> Complete Your Account </h2>
    <h4 class="text-center ng-binding ng-scope"> Yourname@gmail.com </h4> <br>
    <form method="POST" action="confirm.html">

       <!--<i class="fas fa-globe">--><div align="center">
         <select > <!-- </i> -->
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
    <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
    <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
    <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
    <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
    <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
    <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
    <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
    <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
    <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="TD">Chad</option>
    <option value="CL">Chile</option>
    <option value="CN">China</option>
    <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
    <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
    <option value="CG">Congo</option>
    <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
    <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
    <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
    <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
    <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
    <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
    <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
    <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
    <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
    <option value="FI">Finland</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
    <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
    <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
    <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
    <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
    <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
    <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="GU">Guam</option>
    <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
    <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
    <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
    <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
    <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
    <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
    <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
    <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
    <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
    <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
    <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
    <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
    <option value="IL">Israel</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
    <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
    <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
    <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
    <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
    <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
    <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
    <option value="LY">Libya</option>
    <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="MO">Macao</option>
    <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
    <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
    <option value="ML">Mali</option>
    <option value="MT">Malta</option>
    <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
    <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
    <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
    <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
    <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
    <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
    <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
    <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
    <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="NE">Niger</option>
    <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="NU">Niue</option>
    <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="NO">Norway</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="PW">Palau</option>
    <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
    <option value="PA">Panama</option>
    <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="PE">Peru</option>
    <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
    <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
    <option value="RO">Romania</option>
    <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
    <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
    <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
    <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
    <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
    <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
    <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
    <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
    <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
    <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
    <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
    <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
    <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
    <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
    <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
    <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
    <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
    <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
    <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
    <option value="TG">Togo</option>
    <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
    <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
    <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
    <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US" selected>United States</option>
    <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
    <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
    <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
    <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
    <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
  </select>  <br> <br>
    
          </div>
          <div align="center">
          <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Create a Password" required> <br> <br>
          </div>
      <div align="left">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;"> I want to: </h4>
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" align="center" style=" border: 1px solid black;margin-left:21%">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Hire for a Project</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"> Work as a Freelancer </button>
</div> <br> <br>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-left:200px;">
  <!--<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"> <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">-->
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">  Yes! Send me genuinely useful emails every now and then to help me get the most out of Extolssolutions.  </label> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  </div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-left:200px;">
 
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"> <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" required>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1" required> Yes, I understand and agree to the Extols Solutions <a href="#" style="color: green;">Terms of Service </a>, including the <a href="#" style="color: green;">User Agreement </a> <a href="#" style="color: green;"> and Privacy Policy. </a>  </label> <br> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  </div></div>
  <div align="center"> 
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-lg"> Next </button>
</div>   </form>
   </div><br/>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>


<footer class="footer-navbar-wrapper footer-skinny ng-scope" role="contentinfo" data-ng-controller="footerController">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <p class="copyright" > &copy; 2015-2018 Extols Solutions Inc </p>
    <a href="#"> Terms of Service </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#"> Privacy Policy </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yours is also not responsive. text box and text below text boxes go outside the box at 480px and below.